# Use both data from a dropdown list that is based on eloquent's list in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

i have this dropdownlist that is based on larvel's eloquent and i kinda wanted to use both the data that it has ex. the name and the id. To clearly show this, here is the code snippet in my controller

```
$modules = prchorder::lists('ModuleName','ModuleID');
```

then i used this in my view as :

```
{{ Form::label('module', 'Select Module: ') }}
      {{ Form::select('ModuleInfo', array(null=>'Please Select Module') + $modules , Input::old('ModuleInfo'), array('class'=>'form-control'))}}
```

the problem now is that i need to get both the 'ModuleName' and the 'ModuleID' because i will use it in the store function inside the controller when the user clicked submit. i know that when i do this 
`$module = Input::get('ModuleInfo');` the only data i will be getting is the ModuleID. Is there any way i could also get the ModuleName? any suggestions?

Comment: HTML spec doesn't allow submission of anything other than the `value="xzy"` part of an `<option>` tag. Best way is to just do `prchorder::find(Input::get('ModuleInfo'))` using the ID to get the other data.

Comment: thanks i tried that using ` $modName = DB::select(DB::raw("SELECT ModuleName FROM dbo_modules WHERE ModuleID = ".$module))` but had a error saying `Array to string conversion` when i used it. any idea what im doing wrong?

Comment: Presumably `$module` is an array or `$modName` results in an array and you're trying to echo it perhaps. Querying that way open to SQL injection too by the way. Use `DB::table('dbo_modules')->select('ModuleName')->where('ModuleID', $module)->get()` instead (or look at parameterisation in raw queries)

Comment: thanks! how can i use that when dealing with inner joins?

Comment: See the [Eloquent Documentation - Joins](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)

Comment: can you put your answer below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML specification doesn't allow submission of anything other than the value attribute of an `<option>` tag.

Whilst you could put all of the data into this attribute with a separator, it's probably ill advised. The best way is to just do use the ID to retrieve additional data required in your controller which handles the form submission.

For example

```
<select name="module_id">
    <option value="1">Module Id 1</option>
</select>
```

You could then retrieve information about the selected module in your controller using

```
// based on your model in your question
prchorder::find(Input::get('module_id')); 

// Or just using query builder
$rows = DB::table('table')->select(['columns'])->where('module_id', Input::get('module_id'))->get();

// Also, look at the ->first() method instead of ->get()
// if you only expect a single result. i.e. one module
```

There's also some more information about query builder (including joins as mentioned in the comments) on the [Query Builder manual page](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins).